# Foreach loop in the database SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have two tables in the database (Account and Transaction). I want to get the latest transaction of an account in the Transaction table. If I do it in, let's say PHP. It would be just get first all the accounts in Account table, stored in an array. Then select top 1 transaction from Transaction table (latest transaction base on date of the transaction) for each account by using foreach loop on the array.

My question is, is it possible to do the looping directly from the database? Foreach loop to be exact so I don't have to create an application made from any programming language such as PHP, Java etc just to get the data.

Thanks!

PS: I am using SQL Server 2000

Comment: Yes, it is possible in all modern RDBMS, but they have different syntax for it. If you tell us what database you use (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres), then we could write a query for you. For example, in SQL Server you would use `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: SELECT *
FROM
 Account
 CROSS APPLY
 (
  SELECT TOP(1) Transaction.*
  FROM Transaction
  WHERE Transaction.AccountID = Account.ID
  ORDER BY Transaction.Date DESC
 ) AS CA

Comment: i think this doesn't work for sql server 2000

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that it was 2000, I thought it was 2008. For this version, I would try to make a user-defined function and put `select top(1)` in it. Though, I'm not sure if 2000 version supports UDF. The function would be called for each row of `Account`: `SELECT YourFunction(Account.ID) FROM Account`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the latest transaction information of all user...

```
SELECT t.*
From
transactions t1
INNER JOIN
(select max(t.transactionDate) transactionDate
, t.accountid
from transactions t
Group by t.accountid) t2
on ti.accountid=t2.accountid
and t1.transactionDate=t2.transactionDate
order by t1.transactionDate desc
```

Assumption: There is only one transaction associated with the max transactiondate per accountid

Answer (score 3):

If you want the latest transaction for a given account, you can just do:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where t.accountid = $accountid
order by datetime desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: I want to get the latest transaction of all user by using one query only. Base on your answer, I need to enter account id one by one which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use OUTER APPLY. It will return rows with NULLs even there are no transactions for account.

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM Transactions t WHERE t.AccountID = a.AccountID ORDER BY t.TransactionDate DESC)o
```

Answer (score 1):

To get latest transaction of all user, you can use this sql query in which you don't have to enter the account id one by one

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction t, Account a
WHERE t.account_id = a.account_id
GROUP BY account_id 
ORDER BY updateTime DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work in SQL Server 2000:

```
SELECT A.*, LastTrasaction.*
FROM
   Accounts A
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (
       SELECT T.*
       FROM Transactions T
       INNER JOIN
       (
           SELECT AccountId, MAX(TransactionId) AS TrasnactionId
           FROM Trasactions
           GROUP BY AccountId     
       ) LT ON T.TrasactionId = LT.TransactionId
   ) LastTrasaction ON A.AccountId = LastTrasnaction.AccountId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TOP (1) *
from transactions 
where accountid = "Pass AccountId Here"
order by datetime desc
```

Comment: We don't have TOP in SQL Server 2000

Comment: @sqluser according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187(v=sql.80).aspx TOP is valid in 2000